# Go - is it possible to have Google Chrome browser embedded like webkit in Go? to make Mac, Windows, Linux compatible?

Tags: windows, macos, google-chrome, go

I need to prepare a Go application which will be used for distribution, on launch it will open Google Chrome browser within Go (like modal window or single window GUI) and that can be deployed to Mac, Windows, Linux for execution.

I have tried command line execution with Go to Google Chrome but that does not solve my problem to re-size/move/drag/customized design window.

Any idea if there is any working stable binding for Go and Google Chrome browser? (like webKit)

EDIT:

1) how to make it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhcUWEN6uTY

2) some other way: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/oFhXm4Rx1HM

Comment: What if the system running your GO Application doesn't have Chrome installed?

Comment: If the System do not have Google Chrome Installed, it will check runtime.GOOS and runtime.GOARCH and get it auto matically upgraded or installed. And then launch it.

Comment: @Annjawn: can you improve my answer please based on Go? At-least if we can make that part work, then we can use go to trigger it and we can use some external GUI dragger, mover, resizer to controle those popup windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) install nodejs ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogprXGQWrQk )

```
$ wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.25/node-v0.10.25.tar.gz
./configure && make && make install
$ node --version
v0.10.25
$ node
> 1+1
2
```

2) Prepare project

```
$ mkdir /var/tmp/go; cd /var/tmp/go
$ npm init
$ cat >> package.json <\EOF
{
  "name": "go",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "window": {
    "title": "Sample Application 2",
    "toolbar": true,
    "frame": true,
    "width": 850,
    "height": 500",
    "position": "center",
    "resizable": true,
    "icon": "sample.png"
  }
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
EOF
$ cat >> index.js <\EOF
Hello world
EOF
$ zip go.nw index.js package.json
```

3) Run

A) get node-webkit

```
$ cd /var/tmp/
$ wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/node-webkit/v0.8.4/node-webkit-v0.8.4-linux-x64.tar.gz;
mv node-webkit-v0.8.4-linux-x64.tar.gz node-webkit;
```

B) play
    $ cp /var/tmp/go/go.nw /var/tmp/node-webkit/
    $ ./nw go.nw

[image]